# Perl calling subroutine reference with explicit additional scope as cleanly as possible

Tags: perl

I'd like to be able to write something like the following...

```
call_with_scope({
    x => 47,
}, sub {
    printf "$x\n";
    printf "$y\n";
});
```

Where `$y` is bound in the environment containing the expression (either lexically or dynamically depending on the symbol).

I've found a way to do it, but it requires `no strict "vars"` to be in effect in the expression containing `call_with_scope(...)` and the implementation of `call_with_scope` uses `eval` to create local bindings before transferring control to the callback.

Is there a way to avoid either requiring `no strict "vars"` at the call site or refer to and change the value of a `local` variable without resorting to eval?

For completeness, the code snippet below implements `call_with_scope` and prints `47` and then `48`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub call_with_scope {
    my ($env, $func) = @_;
    my %property;
    my @preamble;
    foreach my $k (keys %$env) {
        $property{$k} = $env->{$k};
        # deliberately omitted: logic to ensure that ${$k} is a well-formed variable
        push @preamble, "local \$$k = \$property{'$k'};";
    }
    # force scalar context
    do {
        my $str = join('', 'no strict "vars";', @preamble, '$_[1]->();');
        return scalar(eval($str));
    };
}                        

do {
    no strict 'vars';
    local $x;
    my $y = 48;
    call_with_scope(
        {
            x => 47,
        },
        sub {
            printf "$x\n";
            printf "$y\n";
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: this doesn't quite do what you want, since it doesn't let you set values, but it may be a starting point: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=315251

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. It violates the encapsulation of subroutines. Normally you'd just pass anything in as arguments. Why do you want to do this? What problem is it solving? There's probably a better way to solve whatever problem this is solving.

Comment: @Schwern Yeah, I imagine so :\ I'm trying to write something kind of like Test::LectroTest ... except that instead of using a source filter and comments like in `Property { ##[ x <- Int, y <- Int ]## <body> }` ... I want to write something like `Property({x => gen_int, y => gen_int}, sub { <body> })` where `$x` and `$y` inside `body` get their values when an "instantiation" of a property test is performed. (With `gen_int` being a function minting a fresh source of integers).

Comment: @GregoryNisbet You could make `$x` and `$y` globals in the caller's package and use a symbolic reference like `*{$var} = $property->{x}`. But I'd recommend using as little magic as possible in testing libraries, one less mysterious thing to debug. Maybe have just one global variable, `$p`, which contains the property hash. Then you can `local $p = ...` and the user can write `$p->{x}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I'm trying to write something kind of like Test::LectroTest ... except that instead of using a source filter and comments like in `Property { ##[ x <- Int, y <- Int ]## <body> }` ... I want to write something like `Property({x => gen_int, y => gen_int}, sub { <body> })` where `$x` and `$y` inside body get their values when an "instantiation" of a property test is performed.*

You can do this by defining `$x` and `$y` as globals in the caller's package.

```
no strict 'refs';
my $caller = caller;
for my $var (keys %$properties) {
    *{$caller.'::'.$var} = $properties->{$var};
}
$code->();
```

But this can't be easily localized. And polluting the caller's namespace with globals potentially leads to mysterious data leaking between tests. In general, use as little magic as possible in a test library; the user will have enough of their own weird magic to debug.

Instead, provide a function which returns the properties. For example, `p`.

```
package LectroTest;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT = qw(test p);
our $P;

sub test {
    my($props, $test) = @_;

    local $P = $props;
    $test->();
}

sub p {
    return $P;
}
```

And the test looks like:

```
use LectroTest;

test(
    { x => 42 }, sub { print p->{x} }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the anon sub is compiled before `call_with_scope` is called, so there's no chance for `call_with_scope` to declare variables for that sub.

Any reason you're not using arguments like any other sub?

```
call_with_scope([ 47 ], sub {
   my ($x) = @_;
   printf "%s\n", $x;
   printf "%s\n", $y;
});
```

It's not any longer!

---

Here's an alternative if you're ok in declaring `$x` outside of the sub.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PadWalker qw( closed_over );

sub call_with_scope {
   my ($inits, $cb) = @_;
   my $captures = closed_over($cb);
   for my $var_name_with_sigil (keys(%$captures)) {
      my ($var_name) = $var_name_with_sigil =~ /^\$(.*)/s
         or next;

      $inits->{$var_name}
         or next;

      ${ $captures->{$var_name_with_sigil} } = $inits->{$var_name};
   }

   return $cb->();
}

{
   my $x;
   my $y = 48;
   call_with_scope({
      x => 47,
   }, sub {
      printf "%s\n", $x;
      printf "%s\n", $y;
  });
}
```

This works because variables are created at compile-time and cleared on scope exit.

It even works if `sub` was compiled in a different scope and package than the call to `call_with_scope`.

```
{
   my $sub = do {
      my $x;
      my $y = 48;
      sub {
         printf "%s\n", $x;
         printf "%s\n", $y;
      }
   };

   call_with_scope({ x => 47 }, $sub);
}
```

But do you really want that kind of magic in your program?